# How to implement concentric doughnut charts in polymer 1.0 using Chart.js?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, chart.js

I am trying to implement concentric doughnut charts in polymer 1.0 using Chart.js.
when i try to research, all i find is the this link: [This link](https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js/issues/797).

I find concentric doughnut is not yet implemented in Chart.js v 2.0. Kindly confirm the same.

Also let me know if there is any way i can implement it?

Answer (score 1):

Concentric doughnuts are implemented in Chart.js 2.0. There is an example in the 2.0.0-alpha3 tagged commit - https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js/blob/2.0.0-alpha3/samples/doughnut.html

```
var config = {
    type: 'doughnut',
    ...
```

With Chart.js 2.0, doughnut charts are more alike line and bar charts in that they support multiple series - each series becoming a concentric circle.

---

Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/zuupzpLL/

---

[image]